# combine `axis lines = middle` and box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am illustrating planes in 3d space. The boxed axis lines are great to see how the planes are placed in space, slope, etc. However The origin is very import for my task and easier to spot with the `axis lines = middle` option.

Is there a way to combine both in one plot?

Other suggest are also welcome. At the moment I am just adding a dot to the boxed axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[]
                \addplot3[surf, samples=5, patch type=rectangle, opacity=.8, domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5] ({x},{y},{x+y});
                \node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs: 0,0,0){};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines = middle, axis on top,]
        \addplot3[surf, samples=5, patch type=rectangle, opacity=.8, domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5] ({x},{y},{x+y});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could draw the second axes with specified dimensions in the same `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf, samples=5, patch type=rectangle, opacity=.8, domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5] ({x},{y},{x+y});
    \node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] at (axis cs: 0,0,0){};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines = middle, axis on top,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-3.5, zmax=3.5]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]